# How to iterate through each Navigation Controller cointained in a Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

[image: xib structure]

How can I iterate through all the Navigation Controllers from the tabBarController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (UIViewController *viewController in self.tabBarController.viewControllers)
{
    // Do your thing...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (UIViewController *viewController in tabBarController.viewControllers) {
  // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the question is tagged with Swift also. below are the variants you can try in swift:

1.

```
tabBarController?.viewControllers?.forEach{ viewController in

}
```

2.

```
for viewController in tabBarController?.viewControllers ?? []{

}
```

3.

```
guard let array = tabBarController?.viewControllers else {return}
for viewController in array{

}
```